# How to consume an API using Hive data table column as a key?

Tags: python, rest, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have a Hive data table with brazilian zip codes in a column and I need add the full address in another column.

I found an API with this information (https://pypi.org/project/pycep-correios/) where I can consume using the zip code as a key.

How can I consume the API using my whole data table?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! :) Unfortunately the license for that API does not allow bulk querying, see [the documentation](https://apicep.com/api-de-consulta/).

Comment: Hi Ari, thanks for the answer. Can I build a file with all the zip codes I have in the Hive table and, somehow, consume those zip codes ? kind of an array, or something

Comment: Sure, can you show us some code? How are you interfacing with your Hive table in Python at the moment? `PyHive`?